# Understanding Almost Everywhere Convergence

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I want to better understand the following statement:
Assume $supp(f)=E=supp(f_n)$ for all $n$ with $m(E)<\infty$, $E$ measurable.

> A sequence of measurable functions $\{f_n\}\rightarrow f$ almost everywhere on $E$.

1. Does this mean:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n(x)=f(x) \text{ for }x\in B\subset E \text{ with } m(B)>0 $$

What I am confused is how this compares with the poin-wise convergence.

I understand $f=g$ almost everywhere on $E$, but I don't understand what is the exact definition for "convergence".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convergence almost everywhere is not a type of convergence.  We can say "$f$ converges point-wise to $g$ almost everywhere", or "$f$ converges uniformly to $g$ almost everywhere" etc.  The "almost everywhere" is saying that convergence happens on the whole domain except for a set of points with measure $0$.

To give you an example, let's say $f$ and $g$ are defined on the real line $\mathbb{R}$.  Now imagine a case where "$f$ converges point-wise to $g$ at every point except $x=5$".  Well this means $f$ converges point-wise to $g$ **almost everywhere**, because the only place it doesn't converge is the set $\{ 5 \}$, which has $0$ length

Comment: very intuitive answer. So almost everywhere is pertinent to on which subset of the support they are converging. It has nothing to do with the actual convergence, then?

Comment: Yeah I would say you got it.  BTW the wiki has a good sentence: "One talks about almost everywhere convergence of a sequence of measurable functions defined on a measurable space. That means pointwise convergence almost everywhere, i.e. on a subset of the domain whose *complement* has measure zero. "

Comment: I think that is correct. The important point is here, that in measure theory very often it is not important what happens on a so called null set, that is a set with measure zero. To denote that fact, we sometimes can add "almost everywhere" to a given concept. Especially when taking an $L^p$ function talking about pointwise convergence doesn't make any sense, because $L^p$ functions are not defined for every point but only _almost everywhere_.

Comment: @hal4math Another good way to think about it as well. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

$m(B)>0$ is not enough unless also $m(B)=m(E)$.

Almost everywhere convergence is defined as $\lim_{n\rightarrow}f_n(x)=f(x)$ for all $x\in S\subseteq E$, where $m(S)=m(E)$. Equivalently, $\lim_{n\rightarrow}f_n(x)=f(x)$ on $E$, *except* on a subset of measure 0.

Comment: So one way to understand this is: the a.e. convergence is a weaker version of the point-wise convergence in a sense that the convergence happens any subset of the support that is non-negligible. Because the point-wise must satisfy for all $x$ whether in a negligible subset or not, so the a.e. convergence is more restrictive in that sense?